# Entity Framework CF (DbContext) and compiled queries

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net

As I understand it, compiled queries are not as of now support for Entity Framework Code First (4.2).
The performance hit for not using compiled queries is rather high so I'm trying to find a solution.

I'v done the following work around for now:
Create a new class that inherits from ObjectContext - instanciate it along side the DbContext using the same EntityConnection. Use CreateObjectSet<> to create ObjectSets for the entities and use that conext for the compiled queries. This works (for small queries, the performance goes up 10 fold) but it is rather cumbersome due to the need of creating ObjectSet properties for every new entity (!DRY).

Does anyone know of a more elegant way of solving this?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using DbContext with EDMX. If query performance is your main concern and you need to use compiled queries then don't use DbContext API and write your whole application with ObjectContext API. Using ObjectContext for one half of the application and DbContext for second half of the application must result in code duplication.

DbContext API has some limitations and it will probably not support selective compiled queries in near future. Next version of EF will instead provide possibility to auto-compile and reuse all LINQ queries.

Comment: I'm not using DbContext with EDMX, I'm using the generated EntityConnection from DbContext to create my own ObjectContext which is generated by T4 now. Very little code duplication, if at all. But it feels hacky but not more so than using EDMX and ObjectContext over DbContext. So there is no other way of using compiled queries than how I do it at the moment (using code first, of course)?

Comment: Thank you, Ladislav.  I had to use ObjectContext for part of my application and even though it was quite a bit of refactoring (but mostly just renaming and fixing namespaces), I am finally able to use compiled queries.  I read that compiled queries for ef code first will be in .net 4.5.  It was part of the June 2011 CTP but hasn't been officially released yet. +1